# Помогите разобраться с API Facebook

Tags: python, django, facebook-api

Добрый день. Пишу на `Python` и `Django` 
работал с библиотекой `telebot`, там было вот такого рода значение:

```
elif 'message' in data.keys():
        if 'text' in data['message'].keys():
            chat_id = data['message']['chat']['id']
```

По нему я мог обращаться с помощью бота к юзеру на подобии вот такого кода:

```
mes = 'Example'
bot.send_message(chat_id, mes)
```

Теперь столкнулся с FB. Там API совсем запутанный какой-то 
И я не могу понять, где там аналог chat_id телеграма.

```
    import fbmq

    bot = fbmq.Page(token)
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    try:
        if 'message' in data.keys():
            if 'text' in data['message'].keys():
                text = data['message']['text']
                message_id = data['message']['mid']
                chat_number = data['message']['seq']

        elif 'sender' in data['sender'].keys():
            if 'id' in data['sender'].keys():
                recipient_id = data['sender']['id']

        else:
            mes = 'Error'
            page.send(recipient_id, mes)
            return HttpResponse('OK')
```

Это и есть стартом, поправьте пожалуйста, если не то делаю. Потому что опять повторюсь, документация слишком непонятная и в ней сложно очень разобраться, по сравнению с другими сервисами

[image: пример]

В примерах одно, в документации совсем другое, а в гайдах тем более все разное

Comment: Что в нём запутаного? Всё так же просто, вложенность другая просто, я другого не пойму, что за пример вы показали, там ключи вообще другие которых нет в примере

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan Ключи брал из другого примера, в этом собсна и запутался.

Comment: Так у вас же есть пример ответа, по нему и идите, а не по какому то примеру, тут же всё просто: ['value']['from']['id'] и есть id отправителя

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan спасибо за ответ)